# Change a variable of MainActivity from BaseActivity

Tags: android

I use a `MainActivity` which extends a `BaseActivity`. 
The app makes use of a BottomSheet and a navigation drawer among other things.

MainActivity handles the state of the BottomSheet and the Drawer is being handled by `BaseActivity` since I use it in other activities too.

The problem now is : I want to hide the BottomSheet when user selects an item from the drawer, which is obvious just a call in `onNavigationItemSelected` callback. How am I going to notify a variable from `MainActivity`  that bottomSheet state has changed?

More precisely how can I change a variable of `MainActivity` from `BaseActivity` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want custom handling of a Click within your MainActivity, just override the Method, add the handling that differs from the original code and if you still want the rest to be executed call super.handleClick() or whatever it is called.

seems the cleanest approach to me.

Comment: Perfect!! Brilliant :))

Answer (score 0):

You may create a handler in your BaseActivity and sendMessage then handle its message in MainActivity.

Or as same logic, you can sendBroadcast with a unique action and register a broadcastReceiver in MainActivity to handle with that action.

Or if your case is a lot more specific, then simply create a method in BaseActivity and override in MainActivity to do whatever you need to do.

Answer (score 0):

To access variables from the base class, they should be public/protected then you can access them with the super.var_name or just var_name.